# Disable automatic Wadl Generation for OPTIONS request

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, wadl

I'm having trouble disabling automatic Wadl Generation in Jersey every time an OPTIONS request is received. I've tried adding the following to the servlet configuration in web.xml but it doesn't work:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this problem myself and it looks like you need to make sure the capitalization is correct for it to work: **com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL**. Put this entry in your web.xml file in the jersey-servlet `<servlet>` section.

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: I have added this still not working

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when it changed, but on Jersey 2.28 this parameter is now `jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl`

So you want:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this right now. Setting this property to true causes hk2 to throw an "UnsatisfiedDependencyException" during startup, because it can't find a WadlApplicationContext. Do you know what might cause this?