# Jersey: Disable automatic Wadl Generation for OPTIONS request without using a web.xml file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, jersey, glassfish

I want to accomplish the same thing as this question: [Disable automatic Wadl Generation for OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330770/disable-automatic-wadl-generation-for-options-request), but we don't have a `web.xml` file. We also make use of `ResourceConfig`, where the `getProperties` method is final, so I cannot override that as suggested in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43341597/1539208). I've tried calling `property("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL", "true");` in our class that extends `ResourceConfig`, but that didn't work.

How can I disable WADL?

We're using Jersey 2.25.1. I tried reading [the Jersey docs on WADL](http://docs.huihoo.com/jersey/2.24/wadl.html), but was unable to read the page because of a popup error message saying something about syntaxhighlightingerror/xml brush.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong property. Anything you see with `com.sun.jersey` is going to be for Jersey 1.x. The one you want is `jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl`, or better yet just use the constant.

> [`ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE)

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know how I can get the response type to be `application/json` (as a default for everything, really)? Right now, after disabling WADL, it's set to `text/plain`.

Comment: I don't know. I have never done it. One thing you can try is to use a [response filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) and cast the ContainerResponseContext to ContainerResponse and use it's setMediaType. But that will probably be more than just a "default" but actually a hard override of any existing media type.